# I want to overlay image on top of other existing image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have user photo which I want to put on top other image, so as to make that image complete.

Here is my code

```
<div id="containerDiv">
<figure>
    <img id="someImage" src="../images/someImage.gif" >
</figure>

<div id="buttonDiv">
        <button>Done</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I have other image which I am taking from cache and putting in some

```
<img src=cachedImage />
```

I want to style it so that I can put the cached image on top of someImage also The entire containerDiv should be responsive to the browser window. So, I want to get the css part of this. I tries using relative and absolute positioning

```
<style>
   #containerDiv{
      position:relative; width:100%; height:300px;
   }

    #someImage{
      position:absolute; top:10px; left:100px;
   }

   #buttonDiv{
      position:absolute; top:100px; left:200px;
   }

</style>
```

I want the button to be responsive with the someImage too. But it does not move along with the image. Also the cached image should be in sync with someImage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use jsfiddle to make a demo with your code and your js try as well

Comment: containerDiv width should be set to 100% and all child elements to inherit that width, now if you change the browser width it will respond to change.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I have already made containerDiv width as  100% still its not responding to the window resize :(

Comment: put your css and html on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

i am not aware with your code but try this hope this helps you

```
<div class="div on which you want to show overlay">
  <div class="overlay overlay-div">
    <center>
       <div class="overlay-content"><p>your overlay content,img goes here</p>
       </div>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css for overlay is :

```
.overlay{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 1050;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
 }
```

you can show overlay div on mouse hover/in/out events.